# Firefox doesn't connect to internet

Tags: networking, firefox, internet

Suddenly Firefox randomly doesn't connect to the internet. I can ping stuff, and I can access sites through Chromium. There was an update through Ubuntu Manager before that, I'm not sure if it had anything to do with it. I restarted just in case, but nothing happened. I went in Error Console:

**Error Tab**

```
Timestamp: 07/26/2013 04:44:00 PM
Error: this.docShell is null
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml  ---------  Line: 323
```

**Messages Tab**

```
Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D/chrome.manifest'.
While creating services from category 'profile-after-change', service for entry 'UpdateNotifier', contract ID '@ubuntu.com/update-notifier;1' does not implement nsIObserver.
1374846512577   Services.HealthReport.HealthReporter    WARN    No prefs data found.
```

**Warnings Tab**

A lot of "Declaration dropped" items

Actually while I was writing this it connected to my homepage, but as soon I restarted Firefox, the same thing happened. So it connects after about 5 minutes for some reason?

I tried purge and install firefox, but it didn't work.

Comment: What happens if you start firefox in safe mode? `firefox -safe-mode`

Comment: I agree with @ruda.almeida - by the look of things from that message, it seems a faulty extension could be the culprit (one of them possibly incompatible with the new version). Safe mode will help diagnose whether this is the case.

Comment: So yeah probably it was a plugin, I think I found the culprit!